# Can I use Ionic without node.js to build a hosted web app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-applications, ionic-framework

I am interested in using Ionic to build a web app. The tabs, form stuff, integration with angular.js... everything *looks* like it *should* work great.

However, Ionic also looks to be geared towards creating native apps for Android and IOS. It relies on node.js for services. I'll just be hosting it on my client's shared hosting account - I won't be able to get node.js working for it. I don't intend to develop the app to use any services, so I don't think I need node.js. I'll plan to communicate with my DB via http post.

I am interested to know - is there any reason I wouldn't do this? If I am not using any other means of communicating with a server, will I be okay without node.js? Is there a better option for creating an html5 mobile 1 page web app?

I also don't intend to access the camera, accelerometer, or any of that kind of thing, so I don't think I'll need cordova, either.

Answer (score 3):

ionic uses node.js only for development, things like build, test and deploy
not necessarily for back-end proposes

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Looks like it will suit my needs just fine.